# Where is the javascript console in Safari 5.0.5 for Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, debug, safari

Just what the title says. Where can I find the javascript console in safari?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Firefox's "error console" in other browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648582/equivalent-of-firefoxs-error-console-in-other-browsers)

Comment: Check this out: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 12):

```
Gear Thingy --> Preferences --> Advanced, Check "Show develop in menu bar"

Then Page Icon --> Develop --> Show Web Inspector
```

I'm using Safari 5.0.4 but it should be the same. i'll download .0.5 and check, to be sure though.

### Edit

Wow, i totally forgot to edit this. Anywho, i downloaded 5.0.5 and it still works. Click the Gear, then click preferences, then Advanced, then Check "Show develop in menu bar", close that out, then click the page icon, then develop, then "show error console"

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't find it in 5.0.5 either....

Comment: Works in Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)

Comment: I have checked "show develop menu in menu bar" but they are still not added

Comment: However, after doing this, CTRL+ALT+I opens the console well